# BLE alternatives to Beacon transmitter - Pi2

Tags: raspbian, linux, bluetooth, android

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. Currently my Raspy sends a Beacon signal. No problem to receive it with an Android App. The problem is that iOS can find beacon devices only if i already know the UUID.

I'd like to find an alternative to Beacon advertise that allows both Android and iOS apps to discover the BLE signal and read some information about it.

What about Gatt Server? Can this help me?

Thanks